# Check if a StreamReader can read another line

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I need to check if a line contains a string before I read it, I want to do this using a while loop something like this

```
    while(reader.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        array[i] = reader.ReadLine();
    }
```

This obviously doesen't work, so how can I do this selection?

Comment: You need to be more definitive with your question. "*check if a line contains a string before I read it*" - do you mean check if data was read or check that the line contains a particular string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `Peek` method:

```
while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
{
    array[i] = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek.aspx

Comment: Yes, this worked, first two answers read the rows but consumed them as well, this is exacly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: 4 year later I know, but I'd like to point out that `Peek()` doesn't work as expected with a `StreamReader` is used with a `NetworkStream`

Answer (score 4):

```
String row;
while((row=reader.ReadLine())!=null){
    array[i]=row;
}
```

Should work.

Answer (score 4):

[StreamReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) reads a line of characters from the current stream, also the reader's position in the underlying Stream object is advanced by the number of characters the method was able to read. So, if you call this method second time, you will read next line from underlying stream. Solution is simple - save line to local variable.

```
string line;
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   array[i] = line;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    array[i] = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, can you please explain why this answer is not useful? for more details you can check the following link [StreamReader.EndOfStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.endofstream?view=netcore-3.1)